# MySQL Only do the insert if rows are not there

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have a simple SQL SELECT and INSERT which this site helped me out with but now I need to make it so that it only does the insert for the rows which are not there.

So if the row is there then skip to the next one. I have it so when a user reaches 100 battles it gives them a reward for it but of course if it kept on doing the insert they would have 100s of rewards for doing the same 100 battles. So need to some how check to see if the user has got that reward then if not give them it?

```
// Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where wins >= 100") 
or die(mysql_error());  


$reward = '100 battles won' ;
$rewardimage = 'chnage after' ;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>username</th> <th>wins</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table



mysql_query("INSERT INTO User_Rewards 
(username, reward_name, reward_image) VALUES('".$row['username']."', '".$reward."', '".$rewardimage."' ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  


}
```

How would i go about doing that? Because at the moment its just keeps doing the insert But need it so if the user has the reward then do not do the insert for that user. The reward is stored in side the $reward.

Comment: Have you looked into Triggers, Assertions and Checks?

Comment: Well ive looked into adding a if statement in side the while...

Comment: you need to read up on basic SQL, not php.

Comment: who said anything about java ??

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is **`UNIQUE KEY`** in combination with [**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Also, please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Could you care to explain about the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ??? Im guess it just checks to see if there is all ready the same result and if there is it will just update ? Also i guess the UNIQUE KEY should be in the mysql db ?

Comment: @user1405062 : It is a two part statements and requires table to have `UNIQUE KEY` constraint set on the column. First part tries to insert new data, but when you try to inset an existing value for that `UNIQUE` column, it triggers the second part of the query, which instead updates the row, with had this `UNIQUE` value. Just read the page i linked to .. the will be examples in the text and comments below.

Comment: Ok i try and do ALTER TABLE `User_Rewards` ADD UNIQUE (
`reward_name`
)        but im getting #1062 - Duplicate entry '100 battles won' for key 1 The collum is var im gussing it needs to be int ??

Comment: @user1405062 : It means that you already have duplicated values in that columns. And no, it does not need to need to be INT. You can also have an `UNIQUE` columns with `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from User_Resards where username='".$row['username']."' ")) == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO User_Rewards (username, reward_name, reward_image) VALUES('".$row['username']."', '".$reward."', '".$rewardimage."' ) ") or die(mysql_error());    
    }
}
```

You can pls try this one.